# What to do if I forgot to do a git svn rebase before merge?

Tags: git, git-svn

I'm using git-svn and have been working on a local topic branch for a series of commits and have run into some trouble merging my changes back into the master.

These are the steps that have gotten me to where I'm at:

```
git commit  (on topic branch)
git checkout master
git svn fetch (numerous files pulled down from origin)
git merge <topic branch>
```

At this point I had a merge conflict which I fixed and then did a `git add <file>` to add my fixed file.

Now my `git status` reports that all of the files (included all those fetched from the server) are changes to be committed.  I forgot to do a `git svn rebase` which I'm thinking is my problem.

I'm fairly new git in general so I'm not even sure if what I'm seeing is expected behavior but it seems suspect.  Did my forgotten `git svn reabse` get me into trouble?  What do I do to get out of this potential mess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you were working with trunk, discard your merge commit

```
git reset --hard remotes/trunk
```

Catch up with any changes in Subversion

```
git svn fetch
git svn rebase
```

Now you have two options. You could rebase the work on your topic branch and merge it:

```
git checkout <topic branch>
git rebase remotes/trunk
git checkout master
git reset --hard remotes/trunk
git merge <topic branch>
git svn dcommit
```

You might prefer squash-merge instead, which means balling all changes on a branch into a single commit. Discard, fetch, and rebase as above and then

```
git merge --squash <topic branch>
```

Clean merges will go to the index which you can review with

```
git diff --cached
```

Any conflicts will be left in the work tree, and you can see them with

```
git diff
```

Resolve any conflicts, stage them with `git add`, and then `git commit` to wrap up your new commit.

Comment: This worked perfectly!  You saved me a lot of headache.  What is the purpose of the second `git reset --hard remotes/trunk` after the `git checkout master`?

Comment: You’re welcome! I’m glad it helped. That hard reset syncs your index and work tree with Subversion in case any new checkins occurred. Because you’re new to git, **be very careful** with `git reset --hard`. It’s one of the few git commands that will destroy work, but it’s currently an awkward necessity with `git svn`. Measure twice; cut once.